# Flutter Images from URL working only on emulator, but not physical device

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day all,

I am using Image.network to call images from a URL, as mentioned, they work perfectly on the emulator. But after running flutter build apk, and installing it on a device => the images don't load.

```
 Container(
   height: 300,
   width: double.infinity,
   child: Image.network(
   selectedMeal16.imageUrl,
   fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
```

where "imageUrl" is extracted from a list as a string and loaded into the above widget, such as follows:

```
Meal(
id: 'm4',
title: 'schnitzel',
affordability: 
imageUrl:
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/31/19/29/schnitzel-3279045_1280.jpg',)
```

Are there certain parameters that should change while building the apk, such as network permissions? Because in a previous app, I had no problems rendering images on emulators & physical devices.

Thank you for your time and valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was when I first started learning Flutter, but it was due back then that I was building a release APK that wasn't being signed and didn't have my SHA keys for the physical device added to the Firebase project, thus, it failed.

Comment: Could you add some more details on how you solved the issue?

Comment: In my case I solved it by adding this line: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in the AndroidManifest.xml